# Is a custom module the best way to build out a Form with full custom AJAX?

Tags: forms

I have a project (problem) I've been thinking about for about a week now. When it was first presented to me it seemed to be a very easy solution, and frankly there are easy ways to accomplish this, but I don't necessarily like them. Let me lay this out though.

**The Simple Problem**

At its simplest this project is creating a simple (name, email, and one other field) form that will be available from any page of our site.

**Let's Get Complicated**

I want this form to be available on each page, but possibly tucked away with a call to action befitting our user base. On top of that I am not looking to just have a link to a Webform page, but an AJAX powered form so that my users do not lose their place in the site if they choose to submit their information.

**So what's the ultimate problem?**

I've looked into modules like Webform AJAX, but they don't allow the kind of fine grain AJAX control I want. I've done research into the Form API (Which, btw, if you have a great resource for understanding this better, please feel free to pass it along.), and it would appear that to accomplish everything I want to do with this simple form would require me to create a custom module.

**Questions I have.**

1. Is that right?
2. Am I way off base?
3. How much have I over-thought this project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Building custom module for mentioned requirements would make your work easy and dynamic. Dynamic in sense you can add more links if you publish any new page in future.
2. It would be great if you use ctools-modal with custom module. I was facing the same problem. I had wasted a week for finding better way to get link with ajax form.